# How can github/jenkins be set up so that $branch is always exactly as verified?

Tags: github, jenkins, continuous-integration

Our current workflow is roughly:

1. new PR is created to merge $branch to $release
2. jenkins/travis/whatever checks all the tests pass; the commit that gets verified is merge of $branch to $release-at-time-A
3. after code review passes the PR is merged; the commit that gets merged is merge of $branch to $release-at-time-B

Now, because merge time B is later than verification time A virtually anything could've happened in $release in the meantime. *Iff* $branch hasn't changed in the meantime everything is fine but if it did change the resulting merge commit is something that has never been checked and could be completely broken (been there, seen that.)

Is there a way to set up github/jenkins so that the exact commit that is verified by jenkins/whatever becomes the new HEAD of the branch with no changes whatsoever? The idea being that $branch is always exactly as it was checked? Trivial updates to commit message are fine but changes to merge parent(s) are not.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed this is a problem many face when multiple developers are working on "release" branches. The way I see it this is more Git related than Jenkins.

This is where Github can assist by a great feature they added to their branch protection:[image]

Checking the "**Require branches to be up to date before merging**" will not allow merging this branch to $release-at-time-A since it is not up to date (because we are now at $release-at-time-B).

This forces the developer(s) to first git rebase against $release-at-time-B and git push which presumably(if you're working with Jenkins [GitHub pull request builder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin) ) will run the PR test again.

I hope this make sense and helped u in some way.